How should I parse the expression "в уровень кадке с"?
In Мой Пушкин by Marina Tsvetaeva, we have

сидела под роялем, затылком в уровень кадке с филодендроном

If we had "затылком в уровень с филодендроном", I would understand as "the neck at the level of the philodendron", but I don't know what to do with "кадке". I saw that there exists the word кадка, but I cannot parse "в уровень кадке с" in a grammatical way that makes sense (кадке could only be a dative or a prepositional while уровень is an accusative).

It means "with the back of my head at the level with the philodendron pot".
Кадка с филодендроном means, literally, "(a) pot with (a) philodendron (in it)"
В уровень is a set phrase meaning "at the same level with". Usually, it's used with the instrumental, but can be used with the dative as well:


В летней кухне два окна в уровень с землёй, половина потолка скошена — это как раз под лестницей, ведущей к парадной двери. [Владимир Ланг. Калейдоскоп детства // «Ковчег», 2013]
За машинкой надо сидеть, как за рабочим станком, над нею, прямо, чтобы руки были, как у рояли, в уровень клавишам машинки.
[Б. А. Пильняк. Поокский рассказ (1927)]]


The instrumental in затылком is one of the idiomatic usages of the Russian instrumental. In this case, it describes the relative position or orientation of the part of the body or a thing defined by the noun:


На поминальной службе король с королевой, как и священник, сидели лицом к публике (= with their faces turned towards the audience). [Сати Спивакова. Не всё (2002)]
На цементном полу стояли один на другом два пластиковых ящика из-под бутылок, перед ними спиной вверх лежал военный (= with his back up). [Андрей Троицкий. Удар из прошлого (2000)]


